# Getting error with Powershell and Visio

Tags: powershell, automation, visio

Hi i am trying to generate visio drwaings using powershell but getting the following error;

`PS C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\Scripts> C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\Scripts\tempv.ps1`
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At `C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\Scripts\tempv.ps1:14 char:1`
`+ $pc = $ComputerStencil.Masters.Page("PC")`
`+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~`
`+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull`

`PS C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\Scripts>`

Please tell me whats wrong here ; i tried lot but couldnt get whats wrong;

```
$application = New-Object -ComObject Visio.Application
#$application.visible = $false
$documents = $application.Documents
$document = $documents.Add("Basic Network Diagram.vst")
$pages = $application.ActiveDocument.Pages
$page = $pages.Item(1)

$NetworkStencil = $documents.Add("periph_m.vss")
$ComputerStencil = $documents.Add("Computers and Monitors.vss")
$ConnectorStencil = $documents.Add("Connectors.vss")
$pcinfo = Get-ComputerSystem -computer $computer

#***********************WORKS UNTILL HERE**************
#*****ERROR PART***************
$pc = $ComputerStencil.Masters.Page("PC")
$shape1 = $page.Drop($pc, 2.2, 6.8) 
$shape1.Text = "$($pcinfo.DNSHostName)`r`n$($pcinfo.Domain)"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page is not a property of [Masters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff765149.aspx). You need to get the PC Master from the collection using the [Item](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff765567) property:

```
$pc = $ComputerStencil.Masters.Item("PC")
```

Answer (score 0):

Either `$ComputerStencil` or `$ComputerStencil.Masters` is `$null`. You could just dot-source the script and poke around the variables and objects at the command line (sometimes easier than using the debugger in the ISE).